# Trigger function on observable change knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a checkbox that i want to fire a function as soon as it is checked. I was noticing that sometimes ko:binding handlers are used to handle this but it seems like overkill to me. How would i fire a function when my checkbox is checked? I want to fire the function called thealertIwantToSend. See my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/2qhc8pr7/)

```
<p>Send me spam: </p>

<label class="toggle-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-check-input" data-bind="checked: wantsSpam"  />
  <span class="toggle-check-text"></span>
</label>


function ViewModel(){
var self = this;
self.wantsSpam = ko.observable(false);
self.thealertIwantTosend = function(){
alert('I want Spam!')
}

}



var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to subscribe to the observable then fire the function.

```
self.wantsSpam.subscribe(function(){
self.thealertIwantTosend();
})
```

If anyone is interested the updated fiddle is [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/2qhc8pr7/)